# Use repl_python() inside of a loop

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm trying to run a comparison test that requires multiple iterations of results from a python script and an R script. Using repl_python() from the reticulate package, everything works for a single iteration; however, if I try to run it inside of a loop to get my replications, it doesn't work.

Ideas on how to get a block of python code to work inside of a loop in R?

```
      ###################################################
      x <- 0
      #run this line by line 5 times, end up with x = 5
      repl_python()
      a = r.x
      a = a + 1
      exit
      x <- py$a

     #####################################
     #try to run this, and it just freezes
     #i stays at 1 and x stays at 0 
     x <- 0
     for (i in  1:5){
     repl_python()
     a = r.x
     a = a + 1
     exit
     x <- py$a
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself; unsurprisingly, reading the reticulate package's fine print was key. The problem was that repl_python() only works in the console.  To run lines of python code in a script, use py_run_string() like this:

```
 x <- 0
 for (i in  1:5){
  py_run_string("a = r.x")
  py_run_string("a = a + 1")
  x <- py$a
 }
 x
```

Hopefully this helps someone else not waste time like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to overcome this question

Write the python code and save in a .py file

After this, use the command `source_python('path_to_code.py')` to run the python code

like this:

```
#### Python part #####
a = r.x
a = a + 1

#### R part #####
for (x in 1:10) {
  source_python('python_part.py')
  print(a)
}
```